# What to use instead of paralllel port to practice excercises from LDD3?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, qemu

I wanted to try to do some exercises related to handling port in/out in Linux kernel based on LDD3, however the exercises rely on the use of parallel port which I do not have on my laptop. As a replacement, I originally wanted to somehow use a virtual parallel port on Qemu, however, I haven't succeeded - at least partially. I am able to e.g. request_region (with address 0x378), write and then read something into / from this address. However, even though I write something to the parallel port, the file on the host that was originally supposed to reflect the state of the parallel port is incessantly empty.

I tried to run qemu with following parameters:

> qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev file,id=paralleldev,path=/tmp/parallel_output.txt -parallel chardev:paralleldev

> qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev file,path=./outputfile,id=parallel0 -device isa-parallel,chardev=parallel0,iobase=0x378"

Unfortunately, neither of them has succeeded - in the terms I've described above - the file on the host gets created but it's still empty.

My question is then as follows: Can I use something instead to practice this topic (ioports linux kernel) ? Or perhaps should I try to launch qemu with a different set of parameters?

Comment: The PC architecture parallel port is obsolete hardware and is not included on any modern PC that I am aware of - is there really any point in attempting to use it?  It may make more sense perhaps to use a low cost SBC such as Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone - especially in the context of embedded systems as tagged.  These have GPIO that is far more capable than the PC parallel port.

Comment: If you want a simple device present on your laptop, you could use the realtime clock or the display backlight.